# WSO2 API Manager Configuration to change hostnames

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-gateway

·         Changing the hostnames from localhost to IP / Domain is not working. Running the API manager server overrides the configuration files (carbon.xml and api-manager.xml) to previous configuration. How should we change the domain names from localhost to domain or live IPs?

·         The configuration is not editable in https://localhost:9443/carbon. Is there any other way to change configuration? Even the configuration is not visible in https://localhost:9443/admin.?

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are referring to APIM 3.0.0 which comes with new configuration model. These configs are need to be modified in the deployment.toml file. Please refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Reference/ConfigCatalog/ for more information.

See details on changing hostname in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/InstallAndSetup/DeployingWSO2APIManager/changing-the-hostname/

Comment: We already tried these configurations and changed the hostname. Also, we tried activating and generating keystores using the public certificate but the moment we set the keystore the API manager doesn’t get activated.